# Prices.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys I keep receiving an error that this is not a function and it's creating an error in the app. Dont know what im missing, how do i fix this? Cheers

```
export default function () {
return (
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({ prices }) => (
    <PriceGrid>
      {prices.map((price, index) => (
        <PriceTile index={index} price={price} />
      ))}
    </PriceGrid>
  )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that "prices" is undefined

Comment: due to it being the first render.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that is calling this component as well. Are you sure it's being used within a Provider? Are the context values initialized?

Comment: @simplecreator Nah, if that were the case he'd get `prices is not defined`. Apparently prices doesn't have a `.map()` method when you thought it did. Maybe `prices` isn't what you think it is. Find out what `prices` is and you'll figure out what's going on.

Comment: thing is it seems to work fine and then sometimes it doesnt, its when its when im running this function  

   fetchPrices = async () => {
    if (this.state.firstVisit) return;
    let prices = await this.prices();
   
    prices = prices.filter((price) => Object.keys(price).length);
    this.setState({ prices });
  };

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a empty check for prices?

`prices?.map` (if you have optional chaining support) or `prices && prices.map`